# How do I wait for a download to complete before continuing?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I have this block of code. It fetches data from the API and adds it to a `locationDetails` array, which is part of a singleton.

```
private func DownloadLocationDetails(placeID: String) {
        let request = AF.request(GoogleAPI.shared.getLocationDetailsLink(placeID: placeID))
        request.responseJSON { (data) in
            
            guard let detail = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LocationDetailsBase.self, from: data.data!),
                  let result = detail.result else {
                print("Something went wrong fetching nearby locations.")
                return
            }
            DownloadManager.shared.locationDetails.append(result)
        }
    }
```

This block of code is the block in question. I'm creating a caching system of sorts that only downloads new information and retains any old information. This is being done to save calls to the API and for performance gains. The line `DownloadLocationDetails(placeID: placeID)` is a problem for me because if I execute this line of code it will continue to loop over and over again using unnecessary API calls while waiting for the download to complete. How do I effectively manage this?

```
func GetLocationDetail(placeID: String) -> LocationDetail {
        for location in locationDetails {
            if location.place_id == placeID { return location }
        }
        DownloadLocationDetails(placeID: placeID)
        return GetLocationDetail(placeID: placeID)
    }
```

I expect this `GetLocationDetail(....)` to be called whenever a user interacts with an interface object, so how do I also ensure that the view that calls this is properly notified that the download is complete?

I attempted using a closure but I can't get it to return the way I'm wanting it to. I have a property on the singleton that I want to set this value so that it can be called globally. I am also considering using GCD but I'm not sure of the structure for that.

Comment: **Don't wait, notify**. Add completion handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the pattern for something like this is to store the request object you created in `DownloadLocationDetails` so you can check to see if one is active before making another call. If you only want to support one at a time, then it's as simple as keeping the bare reference to the request object, but you could make a dictionary of request objects keyed off the placeID (and you probably want to think about maximum request count, and queue up additional requests).

Then the trick is to get notified when the given request object completes. There are a couple ways you could do this, such as keeping a list of callbacks to invoke when it completes, but the easiest would probably be just to refactor the code a bit so that you always update your UI when the request completes, so something like:

```
private func DownloadLocationDetails(placeID: String) {
        let request = AF.request(GoogleAPI.shared.getLocationDetailsLink(placeID: placeID))
        request.responseJSON { (data) in
            
            guard let detail = try? JSONDecoder().decode(LocationDetailsBase.self, from: data.data!),
                  let result = detail.result else {
                print("Something went wrong fetching nearby locations.")
                return
            }
            DownloadManager.shared.locationDetails.append(result)
            // Notify the UI to refresh for placeID
        }
    }
```